# Changing alpha of window background, not the whole window

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, alpha, appkit

so i have a quick question i have the method below which sets the alpha value of a window depending on the value from a slider, however the content of the window also becomes translucent and eventually disappears with the window.

Is there a way to just change the alpha value of the window and not the content view inside it?

```
- (IBAction)changeTransparency:(id)sender { 
// Set the window's alpha value. This will cause the views in the window to redraw.
[self.window setAlphaValue:[sender floatValue]];}
```

Thanks, Sami.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SettingWindowAppearance.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000232-BBCDDHGE) gives a way to do this.  The key is to set the window's `backgroundColor`'s alpha to the desired value.  You must also make sure to set the window's `opaque` property to `NO` (which is `YES` by default.)

e.x.

```
// At some point in your code...
[window setOpaque:NO];

// Then in your changeTransparency: method...
NSColor *backgroundColor = [window backgroundColor];
backgroundColor = [backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:[sender floatValue]];

[window setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way.

Suppose,
self.window <--- base view and this alpha will be changed (but exacatly fake).
subView1, subView2 <-- these views are contents of self.window. and theier alpha should not be changed.

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIView* anAlphaView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.widht, self.window.frame.size.height)];
anAlphaView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // as you want
anAlphaView.alpha = 0.5f; // as you want.
[self.window addSubview:anAlphaView];
[anAlphaView release];

[self.window addSubview:subView1]; // you should add sub views to self.window
[self.window addSubview:subView2];
```

You can make a method using above code :)